# java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect integer value: 'Guitare' for column 'IdentCat' at row 1

Tags: java, sql

Here is my error message when I enter my request insert. I have 4 columns in my DataBase IdentApp (Primary Key) | IdentCat, IdentM, IdentLocax

> java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect integer value: 'Guitare' for column
>   'IdentCat' at row 1Requete :Insert into collabo (IdentCat, IdentEtat,
>   IdentLoc) values ('Guitare','Mercier','AAAAA1')

```
public boolean insertAppareil(Appareil app)
{

  boolean ok = ConnexionMySQL.getInstance().actionQuery("Insert into collabo (IdentCat, IdentEtat, IdentLoc) values ('" + app.getCatApp().getNomI() + "','" + app.getEtatApp().getNomM() + "','" + app.getLocApp() +  
         "'" + ")");

  return ok;
}
```

Comment: The column possibly accepts integers and you try to insert a string. Change column's type and u will be able to insert it.

Comment: What's the data type of the column `IdentCat`? I'm sure it's numeric, decimal, integer, bigint or similar. You are trying to insert a varchar value. Not going to work.